# TLS 1.3 is not working. A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, .net-4.5, .net-4.8, tls1.3

We have windows server 2022 in which we have enabled **TLS 1.3** and **.Net Framework 4.8** is installed
but our web application is build on **.Net Framework 4.5**, Thus we are not getting any response from **TLS 1.3**.

So, do we need to build our application on **.Net Framework 4.8** or is there any other alternate option to do this activity using **.Net Framework 4.5**

We have below line of code in our application for TLS1.3

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)12288;
```

Line of code for TLS1.2, Which is working properly

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Comment: i had similar issue, and i ended up rebuilding an application under .NET Framework 4.8, it is working until now using TLS 1.3 without any issue.

Comment: Don't use discontinued products if you want new features and protocols. .NET Framework 4.5 was discontinued 8 years ago. It was fully replaced by 4.5.2 12 years ago and your own applications were already running on that or newer version no matter what you thought you targeted. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2 which automatically selects the best TLS version supported by the OS

Comment: `Line of code for TLS1.2 , Which is working properly` no it's not, that's a hack for 4.0 that actually prevents you from using newer algorithms. There were a lot of duplicate questions back in 2016-2018 when major services started requiring TLS 1.2

Comment: If you want to use TLS 1.3, use .NET Framework 4.8. That version is already 5 years old (released in 2019). The recommendation in [TLS programming docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls): `For TLS 1.3, target .NET Framework 4.8 or later.` That's because TLS 1.3 was added and tested in the 4.8 timeframe. It was definitely not tested with discontinued runtimes like 4.0